# How to get_post_meta in a shortcode in excerpt on archive pages

Tags: shortcode, post-meta

I have a shortcode, [foo], which displays the value in a custom field. However, as it appears near the top of each post, it is included in the excerpt.

```
function foo_shortcode(){
    global $post;
    $foo = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'foo', true );
    return $foo;
}
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'foo_shortcode' );
```

The shortcode works successfully on the posts single, but not on the archive.

What I am missing?

Comment: Further research implies that Wordpress strips shortcodes out of excerpts and they can be enabled with `add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');`. However, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the code responsible for excerpt output in template?

Answer (score 1):

The `do_shortcode` function runs on the `the_content` hook:

> ```
> 402   
> 403   add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11); // AFTER wpautop()
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L403

So, without seeing your theme code I am going to guess that your theme's archive page is written in such a way that the `do_shortcode` function does not fire-- possibly because it uses `the_excerpt` instead of `the_content`. If that is the case, you can force the processing of shortcodes with:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

However, you will need to watch that as some shortcodes may generate content that you don't want in the excerpts.